# JSON element returning NULL

Tags: php, json

I am new to JSON and having a problem with checking at getting the error message when there is an error. My code works fine when the result is not an error, so I do somewhat understand what I am doing.
This is the error JSON that I am trying to parse:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Unsupported get request.",
      "type": "GraphMethodException",
      "code": 100
   }
}
```

Here is my code that fails:

```
$jsonurl = "http://graph.facebook.com/JubilationDanceMinistry";
//valid $jsonurl = "http://graph.facebook.com/WhitworthACM";
$json = file_get_contents($jsonurl,0,null,null);
$json_output = json_decode($json);

var_dump($json_output);
// This returns NULL


if (property_exists($json_output->error)) {
        echo "<p>error: $json_output->error->{'message'} </p>";
    } else {
        echo "<p>no error :(</p>";
}

$facebook_id = $json_output->{'id'};
$facebook_name = $json_output->{'name'};
$facebook_link = $json_output->{'link'};
```

Comment: Why define 2nd (invalid) and 3rd (default) params?

Comment: I'm not quite sure. I am a novice with JSON. This was just code I found to parse JSON from a URL and it works with the valid URL. Would you advise me to change it to something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the url returns the `400 Bad Request`.

By default, you can't use `file_get_contents` function to get the response content when the http status code is `400`.

You need to set `ignore_errors` options to `true`.

```
$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'ignore_errors' => true
  )
);
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$jsonurl = "http://graph.facebook.com/JubilationDanceMinistry";
$json = file_get_contents($jsonurl, false, $context);
var_dump($json);
```

Comment: It is not an invalid URL however. It is related to http://facebook.com/JubilationDanceMinistry (error is based on privacy) You can visit http://graph.facebook.com/JubilationDanceMinistry

Comment: @michaellindahl Ok, no matter the url is, the problem is the http response status, you need to get the error message, right?

Comment: Not exactly.  There is no http error as there is going to always be a JSON object. I want to get the "Unsupported get request." from the JSON at http://graph.facebook.com/JubilationDanceMinistry.  I want if in the JSON the element error is present, echo the message.

Comment: @michaellindahl Have you tried my code? It gives what you want.

Comment: Thanks. I just did. So there was an http error that was preventing the processing of the JSON? Why did this http error occur?

Comment: @michaellindahl The status code is set by the server side of facebook, facebook just think the way you call the url is a bad request. It's nothing related of processing the JSON, you need to get the json content first before you decode it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't chain multiple `->`'s with string interpolation.

You'll have resort to passing multiple arguments to `echo` or to string concatenation:

```
    echo "<p>error: ", $json_output->error->{'message'}, " </p>";
```

Comment: The error happens before the code even reaches this point. The error happens before line 5 when it returns NULL.  However, is this code better: `$json_error = $json_output->error;
 $json_message = $json_error->message;
 echo "<p>JSON message: ".$json_message.'</p>';`